# Global Event Configuration in Hazelcast

Tags: hazelcast

From the [documentation of Hazelcast](http://hazelcast.org/docs/latest/manual/html/distributedevents.html) it mentioned that there are three configurable parameters related to Global Event Configuration:

1. **hazelcast.event.queue.capacity**: default value is 1000000
2. **hazelcast.event.queue.timeout.millis**: default value is 250
3. **hazelcast.event.thread.count**: default value is 5

I would like to ask how to config them in XML way. Is it correct to be set like this as the following?

```
<hazelcast xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/config hazelcast-config-3.2.xsd"
           xmlns="http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/config"
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

    <properties>
        <property name="hazelcast.event.queue.capacity">10000000</property>
        <property name="hazelcast.event.queue.timeout.millis">1000</property>
        <property name="hazelcast.event.thread.count">10</property>
    </properties>

</hazelcast>
```

And can I set the above parameters per event type (i.e. map event use a set of parameters and iTopic use another set of parameters) ? Will it be correct to set like the following?

```
<hazelcast xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/config hazelcast-config-3.2.xsd"
           xmlns="http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/config"
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <map name="*">

        <properties>
            <property name="hazelcast.event.queue.capacity">10000000</property>
            <property name="hazelcast.event.queue.timeout.millis">1000</property>
            <property name="hazelcast.event.thread.count">10</property>
        </properties>
    </map>
</hazelcast>
```

Thanks for the helping :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the properties like you did in your first example, or using -Dfoo=bar.

Unfortunately it is a global configuration because the same event system is shared between everything. It is on my list a long time to isolate the systems. So example 2 will not work.

Comment: Thanks for your help:) I would like to ask about queue size and thread count. Lets say the queue size = 1M and thread count = 5. Does it mean that there are one global queue with size 1M and 5 threads handling all kind of events (all topics, all map event ... etc.) or there are one queue and 5 thread for each events (one queue and 5 thread for one topic or one map event ... etc.) ? Thanks

Comment: With 5 threads and queue size 1M, there is are 5 queues each with space of 1M items. Each queue has its own thread that processes items from its queue.

If you have 5 threads.. these 5 threads take care of map events, near cache events, itopic messages.

Comment: Probably in 3.4 or 3.5 will get rid of this shared mechanism, or use it when no explicit mechanism has been defined. So that every component is able to run in isolation; because the event system is shared, one topic which a huge amount of traffic, can influence a totally unrelated imap.listener.  Also each component should have more control on overload / threading etc etc.